# Проблема с авторизацией

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите, вот поле логина код который перенаправляет на страницу пользователя

```
echo "{status:1,txt:'profile?id=$_SESSION[id]'}";
```

Вот код, который находится на странице, на которую перенаправляет

```
<?php
session_start();
include ("bd.php");
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {$id =$_GET['id']; } 
else
{ exit("er1!");} 
if (!preg_match("|^[\d]+$|", $id)) {
exit("<p>bad URL</p>");
}

if (!empty($_SESSION['email']) and !empty($_SESSION['password']))
{

$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$password = $_SESSION['password'];
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'",$db); 
$myrow2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2); 
if (empty($myrow2['id']))
   {

    exit("bad id!");
   }
}
else {

exit("1223!"); }
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id'",$db); 
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if (empty($myrow['email'])) { exit("123.");} 
?>
```

При таком условии все проходит нормально. Подскажите, что нужно изменить в коде. Вот новый код перехода на страницу:

```
echo "{status:1,txt:'id$_SESSION[id]'}";
```

Но при входе на страницу выдает ошибку, и не получает данные из bd. Подскажите, что нужно исправить в коде, который находится на странице чтобы он работал также как и с profile?id=1? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^id([0-9]+)$ profile?id=$1
```

Answer (score 1):

Тебе поможет `mod_rewrite`.
Решения тебе не напишу сейчас, не помню, но это точно мод реврайт.